# Trying to add created on and inputting current date in Telephone Notes but only get "created on"

Tags: powershell, active-directory

using the code below, i am trying to add a not that says "Created on" and then give the current date but the date does not populate. thanks in advance...

```
Get-ADuser -Identity $username -Properties info |
ForEach-Object{
    $info = $_.Info
    $_|Set-ADuser -Replace @{info="$Info`n Created on $date"}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined `$date` anywhere in your script. Try the following:

```
Get-ADuser -Identity $username -Properties info |
ForEach-Object{
    $info = $_.Info
    $date = Get-Date
    $_|Set-ADuser -Replace @{info="$Info`n Created on $date"}
}
```